# Replace all variables in df1 with same variables in df2

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame, `df1`, with NAs, which is a subset of a bigger data frame, `data`. I imputed NAs and created a complete version of that subset, and stored it in `df2`. The variables are the same in `df1` and `df2`, only the NAs have been imputed in `df2`.

I would like to replace the incomplete/with NA columns in the original `data` data frame with the newly completed/imputed columns from `df2`. Any ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: hey pdw5! Welcome to Stackoverflow. It is much easier for people to help you on here if you provide a "minimum working example" for them too use. Then you can see how they write code using this example and adapt it too your larger problem. In your case, providing a short (3-5 col/row) example data.frame for data, df1, and df2 would help clarify your question and problem.

Comment: Apologies. I figured it out; was way overthinking it. Should be `data[, features] <- df2`, where features lists all features/cols in df1 (see my answer to my question below.

Comment: Possibly `left_join` followed by `mutate`  will help you shoud you wish to replace all the values from certain columns in `df1` with the variables with the same name from `df2`. However I doubt it is aproper R way of data processing. I guess you could mutate the `data` dataframe adding or replacing existing columns by combining `!NA` values with existing data and computed values for `NA` followed by sampling of data. Or make it in reverse order sampling->mutating.

Answer (score 0):

```
features <- colnames(df1)

data[, features] <- df2
```